# Dynamic time-scaling headers for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I don't have any examples off-hand, so I'll try to be as clear as I can.

I'm creating a scheduling application which shows the duration of events in the upcoming month.  I need to be able to "zoom" in and out to increase and decrease the duration of time shown at once.  As I do, the headers that represent when that event is to take place need to adjust; showing individual hours when "zoomed" in far enough, and compressing to smaller groups as the duration is zoomed out, while still showing the date the event occurs.  I've attached a picture of what I'm trying to describe
[image]

I'm using the extended WPF toolkit's timeline panel to store and represent the events in the schedule, I'm hoping the headers can be linked up with those panels so everything zooms in/out all at once.

Thank you for your time and response!

EDIT:  I realize my picture is a little incorrect as it shows too many hours in the last two, but I hope it's still clear enough.

Comment: Thank you!  It wouldn't let me embed the picture in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom in/out can be done in WPF application by using `LayoutTransform`. This helps you to zoom-in or zoom-out.

Coming to second part, you will have to select two extreme end of zoom, and based on that you can set the headers. You can add that in the events related to zoom (most likely, mouse scrolling or zoom button click).

A detailed tutorial is available on MSDN, ([link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ivo_manolov/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf/)) written by Ivo Manolov. Please do check it out.